# Solve ODE using laplace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm studying for my exam. And I've been stuck with this task for a while. The solution should be $y(t) = 1 + 2t$ but i did not get the same answer. This is what i did:
[image]

Comment: This link here shows you how to use MathJax, which is the way we write math symbols on this site. Images are discouraged as they are not searchable. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You need to differentiate $Y$ when you do the $d/ds$. So in this situation instead of an algebraic equation, the Laplace transform furnishes a first order ODE.

Comment: @Moo thank u, but that answer is still not the same as the solution my teacher have, which is  1+2

Comment: @Ian I dont quite understand. can you precise? show me? :)

Comment: For example $d/ds[sY-1]=Y+sY'$.

Comment: how come that? is there a rule?

Comment: Because $Y$ depends on $s$. Besides that I used the product rule.

Comment: okay thank you @Ian